# What is this beetle and what are the strange antennae for?

Tags: zoology, entomology, species-identification

I found this wonderful creature in my yard (I live in the south of France) last night:

[image]

[image]

It was about 2-3cm long, with a hard carapace and wings. It also made loud hissing noises when agitated. I am curious as to what species this is, I'm quite surprised I'd never seen it before cause the beastie is quite large and last night I found it because of the *noise* it was making. It was upside down and hissing like a kettle.

More than the specific species' name, I am curious as to what the large antennae are for. Does their shape and size somehow increase the beetle's sensitivity to whatever stimuli these are atuned to?

---

Alan Boyd's comment below helped me along a bit. I seem to have found a close relative of the ten-lined June beetle (Polyphylla decemlineata) pictured below (image [source](http://waynesword.palomar.edu/ww0502.htm))

[image]

Comment: My guess is some kind of chafer. The elaborate antennae are probably an adaptation for detection of mating pheromones during nocturnal mating flights.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the pattern on the elytra (hard upper wings), it looks like you might have a beautiful male *Polyphylla fullo*. Compare your photos with the *P. fullo* in [this illustration](http://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/page/27416209#page/617/mode/1up), or photos on the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyphylla_fullo).

**edit to fully respond to the comments:**

I suspect you're right that the antennae plates in your picture are just tightly closed up, giving a different appearance. Here's a photo I took of a related species where you can see both appearances of the antennae.

And I think that Alan Boyd is correct about the antennae being used as chemoreceptors to locate females. The [wikipedia page on the Ten-Lined June Bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ten-lined_June_beetle) also mentions both of these points.

[image]

Comment: It is indeed a beautiful specimen.

Comment: Ah yes, I think you nailed it. That does indeed seem to be it. However, whereas the specimen I saw seems to have solid antennae, other photographs (e.g. [here](http://www.godofinsects.com/index.php/museum/beetles/scarab-beetles-scarabaeidae/june-beetle-polyphylla-fullo/)) show a kind of brush or duster like arrangement of what looks like separate filaments. Is that the same antenna that can be fanned out at will, is this is male/female thing or perhaps an adult/juvenile difference? Also, could you shed some light on why the antennae are shaped as they are?

Comment: Thank you! The second photograph is just what I needed. So these little buggers can expand their antennae at will? I guess they do so in response to pheromones, cool!

Comment: Polyphylla = 'many leaves'. This may refer to the structure of the antennae, when fully deployed.

Comment: @AlanBoyd argh! Yes, that makes perfect sense and should have been obvious to a native Greek speaker like myself.

Comment: It's likely the this structure (the 'many leaves') is adaptive because of increased surface area / volume ratio. The more the 'frilly' your antennae are, the greater the surface area, which means more contact between the pheromones in the air and your chemosensory bits.

Comment: @Wajurgmitr yup, that makes perfect sense. Also, conversely, you would want to be able to compact them into a less fragile form.

Comment: Are we sure about this? To me the elytra look pretty different; in the OP's photo there is yellow patterning but it's relatively smooth, whereas this one is very 'ribbed' but lacks the yellow colour.